# JSF single select box with customizable look-and-feel

Tags: jsf, richfaces

I'm looking for a control that allows me to choose a single option from a list of choices via a dropdown box. The h:singleSelectMenu or h:singleSelectListBox worked well, but now I have a requirement to customize the glyph that triggers the dropdown. I've looked at the RichFaces components, but I don't see anything like a single select box.

Comment: Didn't you mean to say `h:selectOneMenu` and `h:selectOneListbox`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check [`rich:comboBox`](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/comboBox.jsf?c=comboBox&tab=usage).

Comment: Hmm, I looked at that and rejected it for some reason, but since I don't remember why, I'll accept your answer. Thanks! :)